# Horizontal swipe for iOS

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver

I need to swipe through radio button.

[image]

I need to slide horizontal in iOS devices. I have tried the below code but it's only sliding the below accounts area that is "Account 1 (in the image)". I have reduced the coordinates also but then it's started sliding vertical.

```
new TouchAction(iOSDriver).press(0, 334).moveTo(0, 334).release().perform();
```

I am new to the iOS automation.

Answer (score 0):

problem is got resolved with below code:

`JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) iOSDriver; 
HashMap scrollObject = new HashMap(); 
scrollObject.put("direction", "left"); 
js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", scrollObject);`